# How to use Func<T, bool> as a parameter for Func<object, bool>?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a method with declaration like this:

```
public void OriginalMethod(Func<object,bool> selector)
```

And I would like to call it from generic method, that has declaration like this:

```
public void GenericMethod<T>(Func<T, bool> selector)
```

How do I do that?

Comment: The actual problem is that Func<T, bool> could potentially call to members of T not implemented in object. Since OriginalMethod calls it with an object parameter, the compiler cannot be sure that Func<T, bool> will be compatible with it. Notice how calling GenericMethod with OriginalMethod's selector works, because T is guaranteed to contain implementations of all of object's members, so calling Func<object, bool> is acceptable with a T parameter. Any of the proposed answers require that you are damn sure your T selector uses object's members or OriginalMethod only passes T-derived parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't pass the `selector` directly to `OriginalMethod`: it expects a method that accepts any `object`, but a `Func<T, bool>` accepts only an object of type `T`.

Of course, you can cheat:

```
OriginalMethod(o => selector((T)o));
```

But if `OriginalMethod` calls the method with an object that is not convertible to T, it will fail...

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a `Func<object, bool>` that calls the typed one passed in.

```
public void GenericMethod<T>(Func<T, bool> selector)
{
    Func<object, bool> untypedSelector = (object obj) => selector((T)obj);

    OriginalMethod(untypedSelector);
}
```

Either like the above, or a one-liner like [Marc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8560117/593627).

Answer (score 3):

```
OriginalMethod(arg => selector((T)arg));
```